# Grails gorm: Find missing entries in other table

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two tables: EventSession and EventTrack

EventSession hasMany EventTrack, but can also have no EventTrack. EventTrack belongsTo EventSession.

How do I get all EventSession that has no EventTrack (zero). Something like:

```
def es = EventSession.createCriteria()
def _es = es.list {
   count("eventTracks") == 0  // I know this is wrong
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Where](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries):

`EventSession.where { count(eventTracks) == 0 }`

[Criteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html):

```
EventSession.withCriteria {
  isEmpty 'eventTracks'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HQL can do this for you:

```
String hql = "select e from EventSession e " +
             " where not exists(select 1 from EventTrack t where t.eventSession = e)"
List<EventSession> eventsWithoutTracks = EventSession.executeQuery(hql)
```

With `createCriteria()` I think you can do the same with an left outer join, filtering where the id of EventTrack is null (not tested)

```
def es = EventSession.createCriteria().list() {
  eventTracks {
    isNull('id')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about EventSession.findAllByEventTracksIsNull() ?